# Looking for formular to copy data from one sheet to another (filter)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

people!

I would like to find a formular that copies data from one sheet to another, when certain criteria are met.

To explain the examples provided below: When a time for person 2 is added in Table2, I would like that time to appear on the MainTable for person 2.

[image: Example Sheet 1]

[[image: Example Sheet 2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2oIT.png)

I've found this answer, but I don't understand it.
[copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another](https://superuser.com/questions/1343583/copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-if-criteria-met-relative-rows)

**I would appreciate an as simple answer as possible. Thank you! :)**

Comment: What is it you don't understand about the answer you linked to? Have you tried it? If yes, how does the result differ from the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If the "Dates" values in spreadsheets Table2 and MainTable are same, you may use Vlookup function to search data.

Besides, I would suggest you go to File > Options > Advanced > Display options for this worksheet: MainTable > Untick the box of "Show a zero in cells that have zero value".

[image]

Then enter the formula `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A2,Table2!$A$2:$F$5,COLUMN(C$1),FALSE),"")`, and then pull down and right to get the data from Table2. Following are the screenshots of my sample.

[image]

[image]